# JSON.parse coming out as a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I've realized that my initial post wasn't clear enough so here's more details.

Jade:

```
meta(name='revObj', content=(JSON.stringify('#{rev[1]}')))
```

The result of the jade in HTML:

`<meta name="revObj" content=""{ companyAddress: '',\n  endDate: '2008',\n  startDate: '2005',\n  companyName: '',\n  description: 'This should be last. Want to go reverse chronological order with current or recent work/education at top. Also%2C some people will want their education first.',\n  companyDescription: '',\n  position: 'Freelance Programmer',\n  _id: 534735ef48dfc379c76a1854,\n  __v: 0,\n  revisions: [],\n  comments: [],\n  successExamples: [] }"">`

This is how the js gets called.

```
<li onclick="changeRev(this,'next')">newer</li>
```

JS:

```
function changeRev(target, action){
    var container = target.getElementsByTagName('meta').revObj;
    var data = JSON.parse(container.content);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof data);
}
```

So I have these two things. When I try to run the js, it's able to grab the content from the meta tag but then when I do the JSON.parse it prints out looking like an object but typeof returns a string. Any ideas?

A note in response is that console.log(data); prints out this:

```
{ companyAddress: '',
  endDate: '2008',
  startDate: '2005',
  companyName: '',
  description: 'This should be last. Want to go reverse chronological order with current or recent work/education at top. Also%2C some people will want their education first.',
  companyDescription: '',
  position: 'Freelance Programmer',
  _id: 534735ef48dfc379c76a1854,
  __v: 0,
  revisions: [],
  comments: [],
  successExamples: [] }
```

With the console.log(typeof date); prints:

```
string
```

The json stuff in of itself gets loaded from mongdb.

Edit: I've found the answer is rather simple and purely to do with the jade. The problem is the html ends up with the content= double quotes which breaks it. JSON.stringify(rev[1]) is what is needed on the jade side.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Please post your code in the question body.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening with the pair of double quotes at the beginning and end of the meta `content` attribute, but you're keys should be in double quotes. http://jsonlint.com/ is uncovering JSON issues.

Comment: Sounds like your data is double encoded. To verify, `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))`. If this returns the object you expect, then you should fix whatever is encoding the JSON.

Comment: ...oh but looking at your link, it isn't properly encoded as JSON at all.

Answer (score 2):

There's many things wrong with what you're doing.

1. You're passing a JSON object as an attribute of a HTML object.  You need to escape the quotations or it fails (e.g. `"` should be `\"`).
2. The keys need to be enclosed in escaped quotations.
3. `target` is not specified, I'm going to assume it's the `head` container
4. You're trying to reference the `meta` tag with name `revObj`, but that's not the way to do it, `document.getElementsByTagName` returns all elements with that tag, what you need to do is iterate over `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')` and get the one with `name === "revObj"`.
5. Use double quotations always for JSON, not single quotations.
6. You shouldn't really be passing a `JSON` object around like this.  Is there a specific reason it needs to be this way?  I'm not entirely sure how anything worked for you.

Use this to validate your JSON: http://jsonlint.com/

**Edit**: 
As per **cookie monsters**'s comment, `.revObj` will work on a live list.

Comment: Regarding ***4.*** Using `.revObj` on a live list will actually work. It'll fetch the first element that has that name or ID. I *think* by name will only work for elements that have a `name` property though, but by ID should work for any list.